# Swift Timer.scheduledTimer doesn't work for periods longer than 1 hour (on MacOS)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift5

I'm working on a MacOS menu bar app. The app have timer which executes in specified periods. If I set the period to <1 hour all works fine, event is fired in specified interval. When I set the interval to > 1 hour the event won't execute till I click on the menu bar app icon.

I guess it's some kind of app sleep done by the system, but I can't figure where exactly is the problem and how to prevent it. The problem occurs only when app is running from the built binary, I never spotted it while having it running from the Xcode debugger.

-- Edit 1
The code I'm using to run the timer:

```swift
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(changeInterval), target: self, selector: #selector(timerTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(self.timer!, forMode: .common)
```

Comment: You must not add a **scheduled** timer to the run loop.

Comment: @vadian could you please explain why it's not a good idea? If I have a menu bar app with NSMenu the timer will stop when it's not added to the run loop and the menu is opened.

Comment: Because a *scheduled* timer is implicitly added to the run loop . If you really want to schedule the timer yourself use the *unscheduled* API.